# List all packages which are loaded/defined (not installed)

Tags: perl

**Please read this question carefully before replying, it is often misunderstood.**

I need a way to check if a particular *package* exists in the current interpreter. I figured there might be a way to list all loaded packages, so that I can search in that list. Let's have an example. This is a simple script which defines several packages:

```
#!/path/to/perl

package Foo;

# some code in package Foo

package Bar;

# some code in package Bar

package main;

# main program. Want to have a list which includes 'Foo' and 'Bar'
```

As you can see, there's no `use` or `require` here. That's the point. I'm *not* looking for the modules installed on my system (those can be listed by traversing `@INC`). Nor do I look for the *modules* that have been `require`d (those are listed in `%INC`). I want to have a list of *packages* which are available to the runtime, i.e. which have been defined with a `package` statement. I guess it's equivalent to speak of a list of defined *namespaces*.

#### What could this be good for?

The thing is this. In a rather large project I often find myself refactoring the structure of my modules. That includes moving or renaming modules/packages. When renaming a module from `Util::Foo` to `Util::Bar`, 3 things have to be done.

- rename the module from `Util/Foo.pm` to `Util/Bar.pm`
- modify the package statement from `package Util::Foo;` to `package Util::Bar;`
- change the `use` clauses from `use Util::Foo;` to `use Util::Bar;`

If I do steps 1 and 3, but forget to modify the package statement, the module `Util::Bar` is loaded, but the package `Util::Bar` is not defined. Rather, the `Util::Foo` package is still defined. That leads to strange, incomprehensible warnings/errors when running the script. Perl won't point to the obvious error because defining a package within a module of another name is perfectly legal in Perl.

Another oddity I came across is when I have a case-sensitivity mistake in the `use` clause. If I have a module `FooBar` which correctly defines the package `FooBar`, but I `use` the module/package `Foobar` (lowercase b), I get an instant error on a Unix system, because the module file is not found, but on a Windows system, a module file *is* found. If I then continue to use the wrong package name due to copy&paste, method-not-found errors arise which are hard to track down. Similarly, I had strange errors with respect to overridden methods from a superclass in a situation like this.

Comment: NTFS is not case-sensitive. It is case-preserving. If you want `textfile.txt` and you have `TextFile.tXt`, your Windows program will happily open it for you. You have to live with that. Now, Perl is neither Fortran nor BASIC, so case matters. If you have `package warnings` and you use `use WarningS`, there will be problems. Again, you have to live with that, and learn to type the correct name of the module in your program even though the file system does not distinguish between `warnings.pm` and `WarningS.PM`. #factsoflife.

Comment: @SinanÜnür: Obviously I know that. I couldn't have asked the question in the way I did if i didn't know that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [Devel::Symdump](https://metacpan.org/pod/Devel::Symdump)

> ```
> require Devel::Symdump;
> @packs = qw(some_package another_package);
> $obj = Devel::Symdump->new(@packs);        # no recursion
> $obj = Devel::Symdump->rnew(@packs);       # with recursion
> # Methods
> @array = $obj->packages;
> @array = $obj->scalars;
> @array = $obj->arrays;
> @array = $obj->hashes;
> @array = $obj->functions;
> @array = $obj->filehandles;  # deprecated, use ios instead
> @array = $obj->dirhandles;   # deprecated, use ios instead
> @array = $obj->ios;
> @array = $obj->unknowns;     # only perl version < 5.003 had some
> ```

Comment: That's the way to go. More specifically, `Devel::Symdump->packages()` returns exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 6):

Walk the symbol table.

Start from `%::` and look at all keys whose names themselves end in `::`, and recurse.

Comment: Interesting, wasn't aware of that. Turns out, Devel::Symdump is essentially a convenience wrapper around that.